# Solving a solved Geometric problem in an alternate way.

Tags: geometry

This question ([circles, power of point, cross ratios](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1574577/circles-power-of-point-cross-ratios) ) has been solved using Steward’s theorem. I try to solve it in another way but find myself stuck at some point.

[image]

If we let $BC = x, CD = y, DP = z$, the required equality ($CD \cdot BP = BC \cdot DP$) is just $y(x + y + z) = x(z)$ or more simply is $y(x + y) + y(z) = x(z)$.

Interpreted graphically, it is merely an equality of some areas as [pink] + [blue] = [blue] + [brown]. 
Even more simply put is that we are “required to show [pink] = [brown]”.

According to a fact about parallelogram, if we can show that $PSR$ is a straight line, then we are done.

Or alternately, we can assume $PST$ is a straight line cutting the perpendicular erected through $B(C)$ at $T$, can we show that $BT = x$?

How can I continue?